# how can I Rotate the image around the center using transformPointsForward and Getting the coordinates of the four corners of the changed image؟

Tags: matlab, transform, image-rotation

I want to rotate the image arround the center.I usesd transformPointForward function for do this.I want to getting the coordinate of the four corners of the changed image.in below you can see my code.thanks for your help.

```
theta=+50;
tform = affine2d([cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0;sind(theta) cosd(theta) 0; 0 0 
1]);
A = imread('pout.tif');
corners = [1,1;1,size(A,2);size(A,1),1;size(A,1),size(A,2)];
X = transformPointsForward(tform,corners);
Rin = imref2d(size(A))
Rin.XWorldLimits = Rin.XWorldLimits-mean(Rin.XWorldLimits);
Rin.YWorldLimits = Rin.YWorldLimits-mean(Rin.YWorldLimits);
[out,ref] = imwarp(A,Rin,tform);
figure,
subplot(1,2,1),imshow(A,[])
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(out,[])
X(:,1) = X(:,1) - ref.XWorldLimits(1);
X(:,2) = X(:,2) - ref.YWorldLimits(1);
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @rayryeng I want to getting the coordinates of image in out image But without the black parts that are created in the four corners of the image

Comment: Doesn't `transformPointsForward` do that job for you?

Comment: @rayryeng no it doesn't.If you run my code you will see that the changed image has black sections in the corners of the image